# whatsapp notification in my samsung j1 when screen is lock

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger

I am not getting whatsapp notification in my samsung j1 when screen is lock

Comment: Go to apps and allow whatsapp to display notifications.

Answer (score 0):

To allow notifications for lock screen, go to settings>sounds and notifications>notifications on lock screen>show content.